# Integrable modules and comodules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. Do we have the following result: $V$ is an integrable $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module if and only if $V$ is a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-comodule? Thank you very much.